# Zend rpc json : decoding failed

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a client rpc json and a server in Zend framework 3. When the client calls the server, i have the error :

"**Decoding failed: Syntax error**" 
because the json decoded is not valid :

"**{"method":"foobar","id":"1"}{"result":99,"id":"1"}**"

Server :

```
public function wsAction() {
   $server = new \Zend\Json\Server\Server();

    // Indicate what functionality is available:
    $server->setClass('\Application\Model\Calculator')
             ->setResponse(new JsonResponse())
        ->setReturnResponse();

    if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
        $server->setTarget('/json-rpc.php')->setEnvelope(\Zend\Json\Server\Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

        // Grab the SMD
        $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

        // Return the SMD to the client
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $smd;
        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    $jsonRpcResponse = $server->handle();

    // Get the content-type
    $contentType = 'application/json-rpc';
    if (null !== ($smd = $jsonRpcResponse->getServiceMap())) {
        // SMD is being returned; use alternate content type, if present
        $contentType = $smd->getContentType() ?: $contentType;
    }

    return new TextResponse(
        $jsonRpcResponse->toJson(),
        200,
        ['Content-Type' => $contentType]
    );
}
```

Client :

```
public function wsclientAction() {
   $client = new \Zend\Json\Server\Client('http://localhost/bac/zf3/public/application/index/ws');
    $response = $client->call('foobar');

    print_r($response);

   return $this->getResponse();
}
```

Service :

```
    class Calculator 
{
    /**
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function foobar()
    {
        return 99;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help

I changed the server and it works :

```
I changed the server and it works :public function endpointAction()
{
    $server = new \Zend\Json\Server\Server();
    $server
        ->setClass('\Application\Model\Calculator')
        ->setResponse(new \Zend\Json\Server\Response())
        ->setReturnResponse();

    if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // Indicate the URL endpoint, and the JSON-RPC version used:
        $server->setTarget('/json-rpc.php')->setEnvelope(\Zend\Json\Server\Smd::ENV_JSONRPC_2);

        // Grab the SMD
        $smd = $server->getServiceMap();

        // Return the SMD to the client
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo $smd;
        return $this->getResponse();
    }

    /** @var JsonResponse $jsonRpcResponse */
    $jsonRpcResponse = $server->handle();

    /** @var \Zend\Http\Response $response */
    $response = $this->getResponse();

    // Do we have an empty response?
    if (! $jsonRpcResponse->isError()
        && null === $jsonRpcResponse->getId()
    ) {
        $response->setStatusCode(204);
        return $response;
    }

    // Set the content-type
    $contentType = 'application/json-rpc';
    if (null !== ($smd = $jsonRpcResponse->getServiceMap())) {
        $contentType = $smd->getContentType() ?: $contentType;
    }

    // Set the headers and content
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', $contentType);
    $response->setContent($jsonRpcResponse->toJson());
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do on the backend, as the string passed by your client is indeed an invalid json. Can't you change the client?

Comment: I changed the server and it works :